# how to write shell script of "removing watermark and ocr" in automator quick action?

Tags: shell, automator

I'm using despeck software for removing watermark and extrect txt from image and pdf file. the source installation source is--> https://github.com/despeck/despeck

I have tested all despeck features like remove watermark, OCR, extract text from pdf. Now my concern is how I implement these features in Automator for quick action. it's taking too much time to remove the watermark or OCR for bulk operation. so I want only one click operation using Automator quick action functionality. can you provide a shell script for removing the watermark, OCR, and extract text from pdf, actually I'm facing the problem "how to tell "what is the file name and how to assign output name in a shell script" I have tried but an error show "to many arguments" check this shell script code.....

```
source ~/.bash_profile
for f in "$@"
do
  echo "Removing Watermark: $FILE"
  EXT=${FILE##.}
  despeck remove "$FILE" -o "${FILE/%.$EXT/.}"
done
```

[Automator Code part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4WXa.png)

[automator code part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOXS4.png)

[Run automator quick action 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il8LR.png)

[after running automator quick action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpNx0.png)

Comment: `$FILE` should be `$f`.

Comment: I think `despeck` should be `/usr/local/bin/despeck`.